# jQuery performance: css vs animation methods

Tags: jquery, performance, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to avoid using `animation` because it is slower than CSS3 animations.

I was just wondering if using `css` method still being faster than `animation` but slower than a direct CSS3 animation with `transform3d`.

```
$(this).animate({'opacity' : 'show', 'top' : topPosition+'px'});
```

vs

```
$(this).css('top', topPosition+'px');
```

As you can see, I can not directly use css3 `transform3d` because i need the position parameter, which is dynamically generated.

**CSS**

```
#flashMessage{  
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out; /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -moz-transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out; /** Firefox **/
    -o-transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out; /** Opera **/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery animation is different than jquery css, first one it animate the elm during set of time, while the other one it just apply the css property instantly without animating.

css tansition could be faster but it's not supported in all browsers, especially ie <9.

you have syntax error in your animate code, it should be:

```
$(this).animate({'opacity' : 1, 'top' : topPosition+'px'}); //+'px' is not required it would work with/without it.
```

if you want your animation to work on all browsers i would use animate, otherwise if you want it to work in major browsers only css transitions would be a better option although it doesn't give you the flexibility jquery does.

Comment: Right now I am looking for a performance improvement and as I noticed jQuery works slower in Internet Explorer, I would opt to avoid transitions on it. CSS3 will just show the content in the correct place without them. 

Then, is `css` method faster than `animation` as I am applying it?

Comment: jquery animation and css transitions would take the same exact time if you set duration parameter in jquery animate equal to the transition one, however the FPS(frames per second) would be differned depending on the browser and the kind of animation. applying css properties directly would be ofcourse faster than using jquery css method or jquery animate. and last jquery css is always faster than jquery animate.

Comment: The animation will therefor run faster using the `css` method instead of the `animation` one? Is it like using CSS3 ?

Comment: yep it would be faster. jquery css method is the same as using css3, only difference is css3 define values at page load, while jquery css can change css properties dynamically during or after page load.

Answer (score 0):

When I can I use CSS animation but tend to use jquery to add and remove the animation class so that the animation starts when I want it to and stops when I want it to.

It can be useful to use them both together.

Of course when using CSS animation you need to think about what browsers will handle it.

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/